# Why my JetBrains Toolbox can't find my IntelliJ IDEA which has been installed already?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-toolbox

I installed JetBrains Toolbox, but it cannot show the IntelliJ IDEA I installed before. Also I cannot open the local projects on the toolbox via IntelliJ IDEA, while WebStorm, DataGrip and CLion I installed before are available.

Is there anything I need to do with the toolbox or the IntelliJ IDEA?

**expecting**: I can use my IntelliJ IDEA normally via JetBrains Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify is it also displays the IDEA in the control panel in the uninstall program? If Windows shows it correctly, Toolbox App should show it too.

Comment: It would be better if you post a comment instead of a post.